# Cannot Ping between Host and Guest VM on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

## [Edit - Solved ]

**Problem** Unable to ping between host and VM guest

**Settings**

Guest OS : Ubuntu
 
Host OS:  Windows10
 
Firewall settings are disabled on windows 10
 
Type of network adapter on Virtual Box is **bridged**

**IP config**

*Windows:*

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.110

*Ubuntu:*

inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

**Troubleshooting**

1. Tried pining the gateway but no hope
2. Tried changing the IP of the Ubuntu guest (since both host and guest having the same IP) but still no hope
3. Changed my network (connected to a mobile hotspot) and it Worked!

**Conclusion:**
I was connected to a WLAN repeater, may be this was the issue but I have no idea how that could be related!

Comment: It seems unlikely that both the Windows and the Ubuntu machines should have the same IP address ending in `110`.

Comment: I thought so . That's why I tried changing the IP
$ sudo ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.0.111 netmask 255.255.255.0 


$ ping 192.168.0.1<br/>
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2043ms


But it did not work

Comment: For internet searchers needing the basics: https://serverfault.com/a/874114/544187

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems something wrong with your network settings. How windows and guest have same IP address(192.168.0.110).

Which network type you are using
NAT or Bridged or Host only

For virtual networking refer:
http://trainenv.blogspot.in/

Comment: It is Bridged. I tried statically changing the Guest IP to 
192.168.0.X but it did not work also !

Comment: change it to dynamic and check Ip address is getting assigned to guest. if it assigned then your guest is connected with network. otherwise you should choose correct network adapter(LAN or wireless) in bridged adapter settings. If your host is connected to LAN then choose LAN in bridged network settings. if it wireless then choose wireless.

Comment: That is what I have already done. The problem was that in dynamic mode, the Guest is always getting the same IP as the host. But when I changed the network (connected to a wireless hotspot instead of home network), everything worked fine. 

I guess this may be an issue with the home network considering DHCP. I have to look into that later because my home network is not managed by me. Thank you Naveen for your contribution

Comment: What network interface? I have three of them - NAT, Bridged, Internal. Downvote

Answer (score 1):

this might help others, but i had a host machine with multiple physical eth ports on my linux box. i had a virtualbox loaded with windows with a bridged network adapter to eth2. but only eth1 on the host machine had a physical network cable plugged in, eth2 did not. in order to use a bridged adapter, you need a cable plugged in.

ethtool eth2
look for linked detected: no

Comment: This solved my problem.  I switched a computer from a using it WIFI adapter to a LAN adapter for faster communication.  When I did this, I didn't realize that I would have to change the adapter I was using in VirtualBox network settings.  Without making that change, you can't ping from either direction. Thanks, this did help me!!